# checking if user input includes a <script> tag with javascript. Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, html, forms, xss

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function XSSPrevent(){
            var usercomments = document.getElementById('usertext').value;
            if(usercomments.contains("<script>"){
                alert("Failed");
            } else
            alert("Thank you for your comments" + usercomments);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="usertext" maxlength=50/>
        <input type="submit" value="Enter" onclick="XSSPrevent()"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

It is my first time to work with both HTML form and javascript. Console

shows an unexpected token { after if loop. What's wrong?
I know it is not a good idea to use an alert method in this situation but I

just wanna check my function quickly.

Comment: you realize that there could be tons of other ways to xss the site, right?

Comment: @mehulmpt yea I know. For example replacing. But My question was not that.

Comment: You should use a stable HTML sanitizer on your server.

Comment: @undefined but I am not a backend programmer. Can't it be done with some javascript?

Comment: While it wont fix your issue, using the onclick for the submit button wont prevent the form from being submitted. You need to use the onsubmit event on the containing form element.

Comment: @ProgramLover Of course it can be done. There are many good JavaScript libraries for snanizing user inputs, but client side JavaScript validation is not enough for making an application more secure. One can easily bypass client-side validations.

Comment: @ProgramLover The general rule is: never trust the client. No matter how secure you think your site is on the client side, the server side will still need to do all the same validation and sanitation.

Comment: Not sure if my answer made that clear enough: client side code is for UX/UI - think pretty messages telling them which field they forgot to fill out is required or why "abc" is not a valid email address. - It's only for handling the non-maleficent (ill-intended) users. Backend validation and sanitization is crucial!

Comment: Thank you everybody for nice suggestions! I will remember and remember all your nice advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a bracket:

```js
function XSSPrevent(){
    var usercomments = document.getElementById('usertext').value;
    if(usercomments.contains("<script>")){ // <-- was missing ) here
        alert("Failed");
    } else
    alert("Thank you for your comments" + usercomments);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**:  Front-end code is only for making things pretty/user-friendly and for making the experience better for people who use it as intended. Backend (i.e. the part that the user can't change) is the only way to handle security.

---

As someone already addressed the superficial answer (i.e. how to fix your existing question to not throw errors) the more important thing in my mind is hammering home why, or rather why not to do it.

JavaScript is front-end, which means it can be disabled and even modified! They can just take out that line of your code and proceed unhindered.

Come up with a back-end solution instead. If you're processing the form there's some kind of back-end, and they all have ways to check for and handle bad inputs. Learn how, it's worth it, and mostly not that hard.

It makes sense to have a function on the front-end *in addition* - if you think there are any people who might expect to be allowed to insert script tags... - In that case you could have a function (with a different name to avoid confusion) that for friendly ux purposes tells them that they're not allowed to insert script tags. Though I've never seen that kind of use case.

Comment: Thank you for an answer!

Comment: if you edit what backend you are using for the form I'll point you into the direction of learning how to validate it :)

Comment: Got a down vote, would be curious to hear why so I can improve this answer or write better ones in the future. - Or at least learn more on this issue, if I'm wrong :)